# How to use Custom Images in Install4J

Tags: install4j

I am currently evaluating Install4J. I have a requirement to use custom images for the installer screens and icons etc.

Where should I place them?

How to refer them from Install4J IDE?

Answer (score 0):

First, go to the "Installer->Screens & actions" section in the install4j IDE.

Select the installer, and edit the "Custom image for title bar" property to configure the header image for all screens.

For each screen that has an image on the left side, select that screen and edit the "Image for banner" property.

Comment: We are using maven for building project and Bamboo as build server. If I am changing images from my local machine then during building in build server it is failing.

Comment: On the "General Settings->Project Options" step, select the "make all paths relative" option and save the project.